# Integrating ZbarScanner with android app

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-intent

I am developing a mobile app to integrate with ZbarScanner. However, I am meet with error "ZBarScannerActivity cannot be resolved to a type" and "ZBarConstants cannot be resolved to a variable". please assist to help with the following code:

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.vscanner;

import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;
      private static final int ZBAR_QR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 1;

    public void launchScanner(View v) {
        if (isCameraAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void launchQRScanner(View v) {
        if (isCameraAvailable()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ZBarScannerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});
            startActivityForResult(intent, ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Rear Facing Camera Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCameraAvailable() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {    
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
            // Scan result is available by making a call to data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT)
            // Type of the scan result is available by making a call to data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT_TYPE)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scan Result = " + data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scan Result Type = " + data.getStringExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_RESULT_TYPE), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // The value of type indicates one of the symbols listed in Advanced Options below.
        } else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste these 3 classes into your source folder.

**ZBarConstants.java**

```
package com.example.vscanner;

public interface ZBarConstants {
    public static final String SCAN_MODES = "SCAN_MODES";
    public static final String SCAN_RESULT = "SCAN_RESULT";
    public static final String SCAN_RESULT_TYPE = "SCAN_RESULT_TYPE";
    public static final String ERROR_INFO = "ERROR_INFO";
}
```

**ZBarScannerActivity.java**

```
package com.example.vscanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Config;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Image;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.ImageScanner;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.Symbol;
import net.sourceforge.zbar.SymbolSet;

public class ZBarScannerActivity extends Activity implements Camera.PreviewCallback, ZBarConstants {

    private static final String TAG = "ZBarScannerActivity";
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private ImageScanner mScanner;
    private Handler mAutoFocusHandler;
    private boolean mPreviewing = true;

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("iconv");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if(!isCameraAvailable()) {
            // Cancel request if there is no rear-facing camera.
            cancelRequest();
            return;
        }

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        mAutoFocusHandler = new Handler();

        // Create and configure the ImageScanner;
        setupScanner();

        // Create a RelativeLayout container that will hold a SurfaceView,
        // and set it as the content of our activity.
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, this, autoFocusCB);
        setContentView(mPreview);
    }

    public void setupScanner() {
        mScanner = new ImageScanner();
        mScanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        mScanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        int[] symbols = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra(SCAN_MODES);
        if (symbols != null) {
            mScanner.setConfig(Symbol.NONE, Config.ENABLE, 0);
            for (int symbol : symbols) {
                mScanner.setConfig(symbol, Config.ENABLE, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Open the default i.e. the first rear facing camera.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        if(mCamera == null) {
            // Cancel request if mCamera is null.
            cancelRequest();
            return;
        }

        mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);
        mPreview.showSurfaceView();

        mPreviewing = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Because the Camera object is a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();

            // According to Jason Kuang on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519120/how-to-recover-camera-preview-from-sleep,
            // there might be surface recreation problems when the device goes to sleep. So lets just hide it and
            // recreate on resume
            mPreview.hideSurfaceView();

            mPreviewing = false;
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean isCameraAvailable() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
    }

    public void cancelRequest() {
        Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
        dataIntent.putExtra(ERROR_INFO, "Camera unavailable");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, dataIntent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

        Image barcode = new Image(size.width, size.height, "Y800");
        barcode.setData(data);

        int result = mScanner.scanImage(barcode);

        if (result != 0) {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mPreviewing = false;
            SymbolSet syms = mScanner.getResults();
            for (Symbol sym : syms) {
                String symData = sym.getData();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(symData)) {
                    Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
                    dataIntent.putExtra(SCAN_RESULT, symData);
                    dataIntent.putExtra(SCAN_RESULT_TYPE, sym.getType());
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Runnable doAutoFocus = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(mCamera != null && mPreviewing) {
                mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB);
            }
        }
    };

    // Mimic continuous auto-focusing
    Camera.AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCB = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            mAutoFocusHandler.postDelayed(doAutoFocus, 1000);
        }
    };
}
```

**CameraPreview.java**

```
package com.example.vscanner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Size mPreviewSize;
    List<Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    Camera mCamera;
    PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback;
    AutoFocusCallback mAutoFocusCallback;

    CameraPreview(Context context, PreviewCallback previewCallback, AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCb) {
        super(context);

        mPreviewCallback = previewCallback;
        mAutoFocusCallback = autoFocusCb;
        mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(context);
        addView(mSurfaceView);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        mCamera = camera;
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0) {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;
            if (mPreviewSize != null) {
                previewWidth = mPreviewSize.width;
                previewHeight = mPreviewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth) {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                        (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            } else {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                        width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void hideSurfaceView() {
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void showSurfaceView() {
        mSurfaceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        }
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (holder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        if (mCamera != null) {
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
            // the preview.
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(mPreviewCallback);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to have been of use =D